# Accessing UIWebView contents from UI Automation in Instruments

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, automation, instruments

I have a `UIWebView` in my application which has links inside that when clicked cause different actions to be carried out in the application. I'd like to be able to test this with [automated testing](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1646-how-to-use-uiautomation-to-create-iphone-ui-tests/%20UIAutomation) so it can be added to a continuous integration build. However, [the documentation is rather sparse](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAWebViewClassReference/UIAWebView/UIAWebView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009929) for `UIAWebView` and I've tried to no avail to get this to work.

Has anyone had any success interacting with links inside a `UIWebView` so you can check that their action is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't find a way to iterate/access links in a UIWebView but would this work for you? Access the page source with:

```
NSString *source = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML"];
```

then look for the tags that you consider to be links (e.g. href=...)

Then you still need to be able to "press" those links. Is it enough that you navigate to the url given in the link? If so, just use loadRequest to do so. If you need more advanced behaviour (for example make sure correct javascripts are run), you'll need to do more magic to parse those and execute them with stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString.